# File upload Selenium Web driver python in linux machine calling a remote machine

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit, pywinauto

Hi I have scenario that needs to upload a file in a webpage. Actually I know that `selenium` will not support file upload scenario. But this can be done in  python with external libraries such as `AUTOIT`, `PYWINAUTO`. But the challenge is i have to run my code in a linux server that is going to call a windows remote machine.

When i tried installing `pywinauto` in linux server i got an error in importing winreg library. Hence i dont know how to proceed further. Please help me out to solve this scenario.

Comment: You're mistaken. Selenium **does** support file uploads, without resorting to hacks like AutoIt. It even will support uploading in the remote case where one is using the Selenium standalone server or Selenium Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both AutoIt and pywinauto are Windows-only libraries (at least for now). If you need to automate file upload on Linux, consider using [AT-SPI accessibility](https://wiki.gnome.org/Accessibility) (say `pyatspi2` package).

If it's a server without X and DBus, I think the question is about remote code execution from Linux to Windows. Good option for the SSH remote execution is [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) (very pythonic & nice), but using Cygwin or OpenSSH might be an additional challenge for you. There are many other tools like Ansible etc.

Comment: `atspi` branch with Linux support is under development in pywinauto: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/atspi